# not having query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, count, having

If I have a table like this:

```
 id      column1    column2 
 1          A          A
 1          B          B
 1          C          A
 2          B          A
 2          B          C
 2          C          C
 3          D          C
 3          B          D
 3          E          D
```

what I want is counting distinct ids which don't contain column1=A or column2=A.

From my table, count(distinct(id)) should be 1 because id 1 has a rows contain column1=A, column2=A and id 2 , column2=A. so id 3 is the only id which rows don't contain column1 != A or column2 != A.

Which query should I use?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Rows which doesn't contain 'A' in col1 or col2 is not 1. It's definitely more than one as you can see. Can you elaborate more ?

Answer (score 2):

This might help you;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/907ec7/22)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE SO_TEST (
  id int,
  column1 char(2),
  column2 char(2)
);

INSERT SO_TEST VALUES
(1,'A','A'),
(1,'B','B'),
(1,'C','A'),
(2,'B','A'),
(2,'B','C'),
(2,'C','C'),
(3,'D','C'),
(3,'B','D'),
(3,'E','D');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS RESULT
FROM (
  SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(column1,','),column2)) STR FROM SO_TEST GROUP BY id
) TMP
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('A',TMP.STR) = 0
```

Okay, let's explain it.

- In subquery, I've retrieved all `column1`, `column2` value by group id and `concat` them, and it will return us follow results and you can try it in sqlfiddle.

  ```
  +----+-------------+
  | id | STR         |
  +----+-------------+ 
  | 1  | A,A,B,B,C,A | 
  | 2  | B,A,B,C,C,C | 
  | 3  | D,C,B,D,E,D |
  +----+-------------+
  ```
- So In main query, I used `FIND_IN_SET(param1, param2)` in `WHERE` clause, this function will return us the index of **param1** in **param2**(param2's every element must be separated by a comma), and if **param1** not in **param2**, return 0, so we could be clear about `WHERE` clause.
- At last `count(1)` will help us get what we want.

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/907ec7/22/0)**:

```
| RESULT |
|--------|
|      1 |
```

Comment: Great answer. It'd be grateful of you if you could explain the logic as well :)

Comment: @PirateX I've updated my answer, hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, that will return you the count of rows grouped by ID when column1 is distinc to 'A' and column2 is distinct to 'B':

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cont 
FROM test
WHERE column1 != 'A' AND column2 != 'A'
GROUP BY id
```

In your example that will return you:

```
id    cont

1      1
2      2
3      3
```

Because id 1 has only (B, B) as a good value, id 2 has (B, C) and (C, C) and id 3 has all as a good value.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: You missed out `FROM` statement

Comment: Thank you for ur help. but what I want is select count(distinct(id)) query. I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand here is `distinct IDs`

```
select  count(distinct id) from test2
where col1 !='A' AND col2 !='A'
```

OUTPUT

```
+-------------------+
| COUNT(DISTINCTID) |
+-------------------+
|                 3 |
+-------------------+
```